# Where can I get the iso image for older kernel

Tags: 16.04

I'm looking for iso images to install 16.04.1 w/4.15.0-31-generic and 4.15.0-45-generic

Where can I find these images with specific kernel version? or Is there a way to downgrade the existing kernel?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.1 (with the non-HWE 4.4 kernel) released on 2016-07- 21, and the 4.15 kernel was way into the future at at time.  HWE doesn't enable until the .2 release (16.04.2), but 4.15 being 18.04's kernel so the only image with any 4.15 will be those after 18.04's release (not a .1).  I can guess which; but I'd have to confirm by opening pages on the fridge or release notes which you can do yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Install .iso images are not made for every kernel release. Ubuntu uses a timed release schedule instead.

16.04.1 used the same kernel at 16.04. You must use apt to change the kernel package after install.

However, 4.15.0-31 and 4.15.0-45 were seemingly never made. That branch was dropped after 4.15.0-29. See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta/4.15.0.29.31 for the most recent changelog on the 4.15.0 branch, and https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/cosmic/+source/linux-meta for the progression.

There simply are no kernel packages for those two versions. Looks like there never were.